# SQL sort order in Japanese breaks when text includes non-Japanese characters

Tags: sql-server, sorting

It seems that Japanese sorting "breaks" when the text contains non-japanese text, even when forcing any possible collation after the `sort` part of the query.

I would like to know if this is a known phenomenon, and what a solution could be.

In the end I'm look for a kana type insensitive, case sensitive sorting, while searching should be kana type insensitive and case **insensitive**

**Here is the test case:**

I would assume from the script below, that I get the same results in both queries (the expected sort order is in the third column). Basically once I sort by the complete word, and once I sort manually by the first letter, then the second and then third letter.

Given the DB collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

```sql
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5),  expected int,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか7', 4,'hiragana no accent')
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが6',7,'hiragana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'いい5',1,'earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カカ4',3, 'katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガガ3',6, 'katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか2',2, 'hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが1', 5, 'hiragana with accent')

--BAD
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', * from @temp order by title  
--GOOD
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', * from @temp order by left(title,1),substring(title,2,1), substring(title,3,1)
```

However only the second version works, the first one doesn't sort correctly:

[image: the two result sets]

It seems it has to do with the numbers in the `title` field, since when I remove them, I do get the same order.

```sql
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5),  expected int,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか', 2,'hiragana no accent')
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが',3,'hiragana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'いい',1,'earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カカ',2, 'katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガガ',3, 'katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか',2, 'hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが', 3, 'hiragana with accent')

--GOOD
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', * from @temp order by title  
--GOOD
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', * from @temp order by left(title,1),substring(title,2,1)
```

See here the results:

[image: correct sort order]

Does anybody have a clue why, and possibly a solution?

Comment: Latin collations don't sort well on non-latin characters. You're better off with a collation for the language or a binary collation if you need sorting on non-latin strings. You can use the `COLLATE` operator to aid this if you only want it in the `ORDER BY` or as a computed column.

Comment: I tried sorting by all the different japanese collations, but with no avail. The weird thing is that without that number , it does sort exactly like I expect. And when manually sorting by first, second and third letter it also works exactly as expected.

Comment: i tried sorting with ALL collations for all sql versions after 2012 and NONE gave back the result/sorting you are expecting.

Comment: @lptr I did the same. I would want to know why it sorts perfectly (with the correct Japanese rules)  without those numbers in the string, and somehow it breaks with numbers. It is if it is being forced to another collation which is Accent Insensitive, but I don't know how to find out.

Comment: I wonder if in the last 3th screenshot the sorting also reads the title the japanese way from right to left.

Comment: @LukStorms the Japanese way is LTR.

Comment: Is it? Huh, guess those manga's tricked me then. Oh well.

Comment: Hahaha.  “In written Japanese, when you write vertically, you read from top to bottom, right to left. When written horizontally, it's read like English, left-to-right, starting at the top.”

Answer (score 3):

Brute-force approach: Checking all supported collations in SQL Server:

```
create table ##temp(title nvarchar(5),  expected int,  script varchar(40) );

INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'かか7', 4,'hiragana no accent');
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'がが6',7,'hiragana with accent');
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'いい5',1,'earlier letter hiragana no accent'); 
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'カカ4',3, 'katakana no accent');
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'ガガ3',6, 'katakana with accent'); 
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'かか2',2, 'hiragana no accent');
INSERT INTO ##temp values(N'がが1', 5, 'hiragana with accent');
```

And script:

```
CREATE TABLE result(collation_name NVARCHAR(1000));
DECLARE @collate_name NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() /* where name LIKE '%japan%'*/;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @collate_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
     SET @sql = REPLACE(
 N'with cte as (
  select bin = unicode(left(title,1)),expected
         ,rn= row_number() over(order by title collate <collate>)
         ,collation = ''<collate>''
   from ##temp 
)
select collation
from cte
where expected = rn GROUP BY collation HAVING COUNT(*) = 7'
     , '<collate>', @collate_name);
     -- debug
     --PRINT @sql;

     INSERT INTO result(collation_name) EXEC (@sql);
     FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @collate_name;
END 

SELECT * FROM result;

CLOSE c; 
DEALLOCATE c;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2500c7320e382c7f224963b9c8f5be6c)**

**Result: There is no collation in SQL Server 2017 that will match "expected order".**

Comment: Yep, I saw the same. Was wondering why adding the number will break the otherwise correct working sorting. The thought is, if I know why it breaks the sorting, maybe I can have an educated work around.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your expected order is invalid for Japanese Collation.

```
select case when N'か' COLLATE Japanese_BIN2 < N'カ' COLLATE Japanese_BIN2 then 'True' else 'False' end
```

Sorting seems fine otherwise.

```
--CORRECT
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', * from @temp order by title COLLATE Japanese_BIN2
```

```
--CORRECT
select unicode(left(title,1)) 'bin', substring(title,2,1), * from @temp order by left(title,2) COLLATE Japanese_BIN2, substring(title,3,1)
```

Both generates:

```
bin    title  expected  script
12356  いい5  1          earlier letter hiragana no accent
12363  かか2  2          hiragana no accent
12363  かか7  4          hiragana no accent
12364  がが1  5          hiragana with accent
12364  がが6  7          hiragana with accent
12459  カカ4  3          katakana no accent
12460  ガガ3  6          katakana with accent
```

**Edit (more):**

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5) COLLATE Japanese_BIN2,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'が', 'hiragana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'い', 'earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カ', 'katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガ', 'katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'か', 'hiragana no accent') 

select * from @temp order by title
```

```
title   script
い       earlier letter hiragana no accent
か       hiragana no accent
が       hiragana with accent
カ       katakana no accent
ガ       katakana with accent
```

With the collation set, adding on a trailing number becomes predictable.

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5) COLLATE Japanese_BIN2,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか7','hiragana no accent')
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが6','hiragana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'いい5','earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カカ4','katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガガ3','katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか2','hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが1','hiragana with accent')

select * from @temp order by title
```

```
title   script
いい5    earlier letter hiragana no accent
かか2    hiragana no accent
かか7    hiragana no accent
がが1    hiragana with accent
がが6    hiragana with accent
カカ4    katakana no accent
ガガ3    katakana with accent
```

**Edit (CI_AI)**

Case Insensitive / Accent Insensitive Results with numeric appended at the end.

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5) COLLATE Japanese_90_CI_AI,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか7','hiragana no accent')
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが6','hiragana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'いい5','earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カカ4','katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガガ3','katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか2','hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが1','hiragana with accent')

select * from @temp order by title
```

Hiragana and katakana are different scripts becomes interchangeable and only the trailing numbers sort.

```
title   script
いい5    earlier letter hiragana no accent
がが1    hiragana with accent
かか2    hiragana no accent
ガガ3    katakana with accent
カカ4    katakana no accent
がが6    hiragana with accent
かか7    hiragana no accent
```

**Edit (3)**

The collation in the table definition will affect search results.
You can even dynamically change collation while sorting to be different than that.

- Japanese_90_CI_AI: behaves (ignores kana, ignores accent)
- Japanese_90_CI_AS: behaves (ignores kana, sorts accents)
- Japanese_90_CS_AI: doesn't affect kana-type
- Japanese_90_CI_AI_KS : behaves (ignores accent, sorts kana)
- Japanese_BIN2: behaves (sorts kana, sorts accent)

Swap out the *COLLATE* below to get a better view of what to expect

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5) COLLATE Japanese_90_CI_AS,  script varchar(40) )

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'い','earlier letter hiragana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'か','hiragana no accent')
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カ','katakana no accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガ','katakana with accent') 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'が','hiragana with accent');

select a.title, b.title, case when a.title = b.title then 'True' else 'False' end search_equivalent
 from @temp a join @temp b on 1=1
```

> In the end I'm look for a kana type insensitive, case sensitive
>   sorting, while searching should be kana type insensitive and case
>   insensitive

For : searching should be kana type insensitive and case insensitive:

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5) COLLATE Japanese_90_CI_AI,  script varchar(40) )
```

For: sorting

```
-- Sorting is predictable using the collation above, predictable, but not what you originally expected.
order by title COLLATE Japanese_90_CS_AI_KS
```

**More (Final - v1)**

Looking at your desired output:

- (treat kata as hira)
- (differentiate accent)
- (unicode order)

Since there's no COLLATION for that -- From @Lukasz Szozda's Answer

Here's one possible workaround:

```
declare  @temp as table  (title nvarchar(5),  expected int,  script varchar(40))

set nocount on
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか7', 4,'hiragana no accent');
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが6',7,'hiragana with accent');
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'いい5',1,'earlier letter hiragana no accent');
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'カカ4',3, 'katakana no accent');
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'ガガ3',6, 'katakana with accent'); 
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'かか2',2, 'hiragana no accent');
INSERT INTO @temp values(N'がが1', 5, 'hiragana with accent');

select * from @temp order by dbo.kata2hira(title) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2;
```

```
title    expected    script
いい5    1           earlier letter hiragana no accent
かか2    2           hiragana no accent
カカ4    3           katakana no accent
かか7    4           hiragana no accent
がが1    5           hiragana with accent
ガガ3    6           katakana with accent
がが6    7           hiragana with accent
```

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Kata2Hira (@kana NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

  WITH filler AS (
     select value FROM STRING_SPLIT('1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1',',')
  ), Hira AS (
    -- 3040 - 309F (Hiragana) 
    SELECT TOP (96) 0x3040 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [N]
    FROM filler x JOIN filler y on 1=1
  ), Kata AS (
    -- 30A0 - 30FF (Katakana)
    SELECT TOP (96) 0x30A0 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [N]
    FROM filler x JOIN filler y on 1=1
  ) 
  SELECT @kana = REPLACE(@kana, NCHAR(Kata.[N]), NCHAR(Hira.[N]))
     FROM Hira JOIN Kata ON NCHAR(Hira.[N]) COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS = NCHAR(Kata.[N]) COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS

  RETURN @kana;

END;

GO
```

Post workaround thoughts:

Just a misc FYI while I was checking things out, it doesn't appear unique to non-japanese characters.

Replace 2 and 1 with い, and あ, and the default collation behaves consistently.

```
-- Implied Kana Insensitive vs JAPANESE_CS_AS_KS
select case when N'カ' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS < N'ガ' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS then 'True' else 'False' end as want_true union all
select case when N'カ2' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS < N'ガ1' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS then 'True' else 'False' end union all
select case when N'カb' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS < N'ガa' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS then 'True' else 'False' end union all 
select case when N'カい' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS < N'ガあ' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS then 'True' else 'False' end union all
select case when N'1カい' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS < N'2ガあ' COLLATE JAPANESE_CS_AS then 'True' else 'False' end -- sanity check to make sure we're not reading right to left...haha
```

```
want_true
True
False
False
False
True
```

The why would be really interesting to know...

The plausible theory: accent sensitivity ordering is applied as a second pass after kana insensitivity over the field (instead of per character).

Comment: The trick "kana-type" sensitivity. Hiragana and katakana are different scripts but are interchangeable. So with a kana-type insensitive collation, you will see that hiragana and katana without accent will come before hiragana and katakana with accent. With other words you'll see sorting of no-accent vs yes-accent, and not sorting hiragana vs katakana (like in the collation BIN/BIN2)

Comment: Switching to collation Japanese_90_CI_AI/Japanese_90_CI_AS, gives the expected behavior interchangeable with and without accent consideration.   The non Japanese character added at the end still sorts as expected.   Adding results to post.

Comment: Thanks for all the work. However it seems like the default collation I've used works perfect (doing exactly what I want) , however once adding the number it goes haywire. Why does adding a number make it go crazy?

Comment: You might need to give up on that quest, and settle with the default collation is not perfect since it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I guess you are right. Although I haven't found the true answer I was looking for, I award the bounty to you because of the investment you made.Thanks for all your help!